# Hadoop HDFS - Keep many part files or concat?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

After running a map-reduce job in Hadoop, the result is a directory with part files. The number of part files depend on the number of reducers, and can reach dozens (80 in my case).

Does keeping multiple part files affect the performance of future map-reduce operations, to the better or worse? Will taking an extra reduction step and merging all the parts improve or worsen the speed of further processing?

Please refer only to map-reduce performance issues. I don't care about splitting or merging these results in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running further mapreduce operations on the part directory should have little to no impact on overall performance.

The reason is the first step Hadoop does is split the data in the input directory according to the size and places the split data onto the Mappers. Since it's already splitting the data into separate chunks, splitting one file vs many shouldn't impact performance, the amount of data being transferred over the network should be roughly equal, as should the amount of processing and disk time.

There might be some degenerate cases where part files will be slower.  For example instead of 1 large file you had thousands/millions of part files. I also can think of situations where having many part files would be faster. For example, if you don't have splittable files (not usually the case unless you are using certain compression schemes), then you would have to put your 1 big file on a single mapper since its unsplittable, where the many part files would be distributed more or less as normal.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what the next task needs to do.

If you have analytics data and you have 80 files per (partially processed) input day then you have a huge performance problem if the next job needs to combine the data over the last two years.

If however you have only those 80 then I wouldn't worry about it.